# how can i call a url from template in Django

Tags: python, django

on my url.py i have this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^pag1_x/',pagx_view, name="url_1"),
    url(r'^pag2_y/',pagy_view, name="url_2"),
    url(r'^pag3_z/',pagz_view, name="url_3"),
]
```

on my template i have the follow code.

```
{% for t in list %}
  {{t.description}}
  <button id="{{t.id}}">BOOK NOW</button>
  <a href="{% url 'url_1' %}">LEARN MORE</a>
{% endfor %}
```

On the template, I want to iterate using the list, the list has information that I have on my database and, in the database I have the url name so what I want to do is something like this:

```
<a href=" {% url '{{t.urlName}}' %} ">LEARN MORE</a>
```

And the final result will be:

```
<a href=" {% url 'url_1' %} ">LEARN MORE</a>
<a href=" {% url 'url_2' %} ">LEARN MORE</a>
<a href=" {% url 'url_3' %} ">LEARN MORE</a>
```

The problem is that the method that I am using doesn't work. Can anyone tell me one method for making it work?

Comment: Where is the method you are using and what does "doesn't work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: Also, as an aside, what do the urls relate to? I see you're not fully using regex so my thinking is that you're missing out on using regex matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like:

```
<a href="{% url t.urlName %}">LEARN MORE</a>
```